# Add number to a string before the last character in the string using regex in pyspark

Tags: python, regex, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I need to add the same number before the last character in a string (thats in a column of a spark dataframe) using `pyspark`.
For example, say I have the string `2020_week4` or `2021_week5`. I need to add a zero in front of  4 and the 5 like so: `2020_week04` or `2021_week05`. The larger context is that the replacement is conditional -only for single digit weeks. So something along the lines of:

```
df.withColumn('week', when(len(col("week")) == 10, regexp_replace(week, REGEX_PATTERN, "0")).otherwise(col("week")))
```

Things to note, the `week` column will always be 10 characters long for the single digit strings that need replacing.

Per @thefourthbird 's suggestion in regards to the regex statement, I tried the following:

```
df1.withColumn('week', when(len(col("week")) == 10, regexp_replace(week, "^\d{4}_week(?=\d$)", "$00")).otherwise(col("week")))
```

The error I'm getting has nothing to do with the regex itself but rather how to implement regex in general in pyspark. Error:

```
TypeError: object of type 'Column' has no len()
```

I also tried:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df1.withColumn('week', when(F.length("week") == 10, regexp_replace(week, "^\d{4}_week(?=\d$)", "$00")).otherwise(col("week")))
```

Error:

```
NameError: name 'week' is not defined
```

UPDATE:

```
df10.withColumn('week', when(length(col('week')) == 10, regexp_replace("week", "(?<=k)(?=\d$)", "0")).otherwise(col("week")))
```

Comment: perhaps `(?<=k)(?=\d$)`?

Comment: Or `^\d{4}_week(?=\d$)` and replace with `$00`

Comment: Thanks, so i guess part of my issue is implementing this in pyspark, I'll update with the error i get when trying a legit regex.

Comment: Thanks @Nick your suggestion worked.

Comment: @CyrusMohammadian no worries - I'm glad it was useful. Note you shouldn't need the length test, as this regex will only match something that ends with a `k` and a single digit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `substring` and `concat` functions which will work for any string (no need to use regex) :

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F


df = spark.createDataFrame([("2020_week4",), ("2021_week5",)], ["value"])

df.withColumn(
    "value",
    F.concat(
        F.expr("substring(value, 1, length(value)-1)"),
        F.lit('0'),
        F.substring("value", -1, 1)
    )
).show()

#+-----------+
#|      value|
#+-----------+
#|2020_week04|
#|2021_week05|
#+-----------+
```